# I can't create React Native project with npx: react-native: command not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, npx

When I run 'npx react-native init MyProject' for the first time it said react-native will download but I accidentally terminate.
When I tried again it throws 'react-native: command not found' error.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted all files associated with react native from '~/.npm/_npx/node_modules' and now I can create react native project.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing some packages look at https://brew.sh/. I remember installing yarn from here let me use npx to work with react native.

Comment: I'm already installed node(it includes npm and npx) from homebrew.Also I can use npx for create react js app but I can't use it for create react native app